# Get selected radio button in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following code and I this error:

[image: one]

## Code

`xml file`

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/paymentMethod"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Cash"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/cash" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Online"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/online" />
</RadioGroup>
```

`fragment`

```
val payment_method: RadioButton = root.findViewById(R.id.paymentMethod)
val weight: EditText = root.findViewById(R.id.kilo)
val item: EditText = root.findViewById(R.id.item)
val updateButton: Button = root.findViewById(R.id.update_btn)

updateButton.setOnClickListener{
    // val mPayment = payment_method.text.toString().trim()

    val selectedRadioButtonId: Int = payment_method.checkedRadioButtonId
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    if (selectedRadioButtonId != -1) {
        selectedRadioButton = root.findViewById(selectedRadioButtonId)
        val string: String = selectedRadioButton.text.toString()


        val mPayment = string.trim()
        val mWeight = weight.text.toString().trim()
        val mItem = item.text.toString().trim()

        Log.d("test1:", mPayment + "," + mWeight + "," + mItem)

        if(mWeight.isNotEmpty()){
            UpdateOrder(mPayment.toString(), mWeight, mItem)
        } else {
            payment_method.error = "Payment is required."
            weight.error = "Weight is required."
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Select Payment.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you are using `RadioGroup` for `paymentMethod` and casting it to `RadioButton` in your code which does not have the method you are trying to use,

```
val payment_method: RadioGroup = root.findViewById(R.id.paymentMethod)
```

Comment: Happens all the time :) please accept if this solved your question

Comment: sorry it needed 10 minutes then I forgot :-p